# Block form resize and show a hint when hovering

Tags: delphi, resize

**Delphi 11**
How to make it so that when you hover the cursor over the resizing of the form, a cross appears with some inscription like: "Do not resize" and it was impossible to resize the form?

I need to block my first form resize when I call my second form. I'm quite new to Delphi, can you help me, please?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
  Form1.Caption:= 'Main';
  Form1.BorderStyle:= bsSingle;
  //And Form1.OnCanResize() or in some other way?
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Caption:= 'Main Form';
  Form1.BorderStyle:= bsSizeable;
  Form2.Hide;
end;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The question is settled.

"If you don't like the answer it's doesn't mean that it's not right. But continue to delete my comments :)"

It's so sad when professionals cannot help you but only express arrogance. Carry on, you are so funny)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
  Form1.Caption:= 'Main';
  Form1.BorderStyle:= bsSingle;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Caption:= 'Main Form';
  Form1.BorderStyle:= bsSizeable;
  Form1.Cursor:= crDefault;
  Form1.Hint:= '';
  Form1.ShowHint:= False;
  Form2.Hide;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject); //Interval = 1
var
  pt: TPoint;
  Width, Heigth: Integer;
begin
  GetCursorPos(pt);
  if Form2.Visible then
    begin
      if (ScreenToClient(pt).X > ClientWidth - 10) or (ScreenToClient(pt).Y > ClientHeight - 10) then
        begin
          Cursor:= crNo;
          Hint:= 'No resize';
          ShowHint:= True;
        end
      else
        begin
          Cursor:= crDefault;
          Hint:= '';
          ShowHint:= False;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: So the form will have hint "No resize" for the rest of its lifetime?

Comment: Not the form itself, its border and only when Form2 is visible*

Comment: Uh... bad idea, I see.

Comment: So... nobody can help?

Comment: Well, the reason you get so few answers (even though there are many SO users that are able to answer it rather easily) is that your entire premise appears suspicious. The behaviour you want is non-standard on the Windows platform. Maybe your *actual* problem has a completely different solution. And even if we disregard this, you clearly do know how to make the main form non-resizable. But why do you need the cursor and hint? Isn't it enough that the cursor *isn't* changed into a resize cursor?

Comment: I do not understand what is suspicious here, but all these are the conditions of my assignment. I didn't want to use XY mouse pos, as I thought that it could be somehow much easier to write everything into some kind of resize event

Comment: If you have a look at your Windows apps (Notepad, Regedit, WordPad, Word, Excel, Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc.), you will find that it is *very* uncommon that a resizeable window mutates into a non-resizeable window. I don't you can find a single example of such a window if you are allowed only one hour to look for it! And, as I said, even if this would be a sensible thing to do, the lack of the resize cursor should be clear enough. Windows has behaved like that for almost 30 years now. You won't find any window with a "no" cursor on the sizing border either!

Comment: Having said that, I managed to make a window behave like you wish by having `BorderStyle = bsSizeable`, handling the `WM_SETCURSOR` message, and using a one-line `OnCanResize` handler.

Comment: Perhaps you want to block not only the resizing of your main form, but the entire form? *That* is extremely common. The trick here is to show your second form *modally*: `Form2.ShowModal` instead of `Form2.Show`.

Comment: Sorry, but an ms-timer for such purpose is not in my toolbox. The first solution to consider (`ShowModal`) is suggested by @AndreasRejbrand. If your homework task demands something else, use `OnCanResize` (you already were close). As you only need to allow or deny the resizing of the form `Form1` based on the visibility of `Form2`, assign the `Resize` parameter the inverse of form2 visibility. Simple!